# Angularjs not working after html is added with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

My issue is when I load the page first time the `angular` is working pretty well. but when I try to use same thing when my `html` is loaded with ajax it is not working at all. nor I can see any relevant error in console.

javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize','ui.utils']);

myApp.controller('CtrlPerformanceByTrack', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(site_url + 'performance/?method=get_performance_by_track_data').success(function(data, status) {
        /*console.log(data.data);
         data=[{"title":"title 1","length":"3:02","plays":4,"sales":2,"likes":8},
         {"title":"title 1","length":"3:02","plays":4,"sales":2,"likes":8}]
         console.log(data);*/
        $scope.tracks = data.data;
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = status;
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div data-ele="PerformanceByTrackApp" class="track-block" ng-controller="CtrlPerformanceByTrack">
            <div class="title">
                Performance by track
            </div>
            <div class="search-block">               
                <form>
                    <div class="content fr">
                        <div class="left-input">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Track" ng-model="searchTrack">

                        </div>
                        <div class="right-icon-block">
                            <span class="icon-magnifying42 search-icon"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="table-block">
                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive track-table">
                    <thead class="title">
                        <th style="width:50%;">Title</th>
                        <th style="width:13%;">Length</th>
                        <th style="width:13%;">Plays</th>
                        <th style="width:13%;">Sales</th>
                        <th style="width:14%;">Likes</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in tracks | filter:searchTrack">
                        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.length}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.plays}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.sales}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.likes}}</td>
                    </tr>


                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the sample is at below url:
http://engagev2.ncryptedprojects.com/performance

to call the same page via ajax click performance tab at left.

Comment: have you used ng-bind-html to display html content??

Comment: have you debug data in tracks ?

Comment: @Keshav  the entire content is not loaded with ng-bind-html when called with ajax

Comment: what is `searchTrack` here you are filtering with?

Comment: try to remove the filter, maybe that is your problem. also switch to '.then' in your http response.

Comment: @Poonam the searchTrack is used to filter data with search bar value

Comment: What you do in your ajax call?

Comment: when you click on performance tab, this url `site_url + 'performance/?method=get_performance_by_track_data'` is not running

Comment: when you click on performance tab you get a `<div id="content">` with `style="display:none"`... you should show this `div`

Comment: *"when my html is loaded with ajax"* ... There is nothing like that shown in the question. Question should be self contained and provide a [mcve] s well as clear statement about what problem is

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this partial HTML via AJAX, then it should be properly inserted. You have to use angular `$compile` service. Simplified example below.

```
...
var template = getTemplate();
var compiledElement = $compile(template)($scope);
element.append(compiledElement);
...
```

Here is the link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile